# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Passport.js Express.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth, express, cors

Помогите, пожалуйста, уже все что можно перепробовал.
Я хочу сделать авторизацию через Passport.js используя FacebookStrategy. Код на сервере:

```
//... подключение модулей
var app = express();
app.use(cors()); //этот модуль должен разрешить кроссдоменные запросы, 
                 //но он почему-то не работает
var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
var FACEBOOK_APP_ID = "***************"; //тут вставлены мои ключ
var FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET = "******************************"; //и секрет

passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
        clientSecret: FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
        callbackURL: "http://localhost/auth/facebook/callback"
    },
    function (token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        process.nextTick(function() {
            new User({'id_facebook': profile.id}).fetch().then(function (user) {
                if (user) {
                    return done(null, user); // user found, return that user
                } else {
                    var u = {
                        id: uuid.v4(),
                        nick: profile.emails[0].value.split('@')[0],
                        name: profile.displayName,
                        email: profile.emails[0].value,
                        pswhash: bcrypt.hashSync('facebook'),
                        id_facebook: profile.id
                    };

                    knex('users').insert(u)
                        .then(function () {
                            new User({'id': u.id})
                                .fetch()
                                .then(function (user) {
                                    return done(null, user);
                                })
                                .catch(function (err) {
                                    done(err);
                                });
                        })
                        .catch(function (err) {
                            done(err);
                        });
                }
            })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    done(err);
                });
        });
    }));

//...другие middleware

app.get('/auth/facebook',
        passport.authenticate('facebook', {scope: ['email', 'user_birthday', 'user_likes']}),
    function (req, res) {

    });

app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
    passport.authenticate('facebook', {failureRedirect: '/main'}),
    function (req, res) {
        res.redirect('/users/' + req.user.id);
    });
```

Код на клиенте (AngularJS, кнопка, по клику вызывает функция ниже):

```
$scope.loginWith = function(social) {
            $http.get('/auth/' + social).success(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        };
```

Когда я в адресную строку прописываю localhost/auth/facebook, то авторизация срабатывает! А когда по кнопке нажимаю - выдает ошибку:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=…allback&scope=email%2Cuser_birthday%2Cuser_likes&client_id=490483854451281. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку авторизация срабатывала только при переходе по ссылке, вместо обращения через JavaScript я использовал обычный тег . Чтобы ангулар не изменял ссылку, я добавил target="_self".

```
 <a href="http://localhost/auth/facebook" target="_self">Facebook</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка означает что вы пытаетесь получить данные у сервера facebook которые он таким вот методом не предоставляет... То есть это такие данные которые доступны только внутри домена facbeeok.com

Comment: Когда я в адресную строку прописываю http://localhost/auth/facebook, то авторизация срабатывает! А когда по кнопке нажимаю - выдает ошибку. Вряд ли это связано с фейсбуком.